# Renderscript limitation size of array

Tags: android, arrays, matrix, parallel-processing, renderscript

I'm doing matrix multiplication in Renderscript. I have my java file which prepares all the arrays. In my Renderscript I have global variables which will be set by the java file. But I have seen there is a limitation. If I want to do a multiplication with 37x37 matrix the results still right. If I do a 38x38 matrix multplication the results are no longer correct. After the first row of the final result the calculation results are not correct. I guess there is a limitation.
37*37 = 1369

```
int vectorcol[1369];
int matrixA[1369];
int matrixB[1369];
```

I did now a dynamic Array Allocation in Java and RenderScript. That works fine, but it is still the same problem. Till a matrixsize of 37 it works fine. Starting with a matrixsize of 38 it won't return correct results. I don't know where the problem is.

How can I do this in Renderscript?

[1] http://docs.eoeandroid.com/guide/topics/renderscript/advanced.html#mem-allocation

Comment: Its interesting. I started my app on the Nexus 10 tablet and there I could run the matrix multiplication app till 93x93 matrices without false computation. So does anyone know if it restricted by a hardware issue?